# Filter out a combination of three pairs in a vector. A more parsimonious way?

Tags: python, r, matlab, permutation

I'm trying to find a nicer way of filtering out the seldom case that three consecutive pairs happen to arise during a permutation of a vector of three pairs. Here is the code I have. This is written in Matlab, but I guess it would apply to anything else, like Python or R.

```
    %// randomize 6-sequence of 3 pitches
    %// This loop makes sure that in each sequence the two conditions are
    %// met:
    %// i.  each syllable/speaker occured at least twice,
    %// ii. changes btw. 2 consec. syl/spk occured 2 and 3 times within 
    %//     one sequence.
    ok = 0;
    while ~ok
        %// Randomly permute sequence.
        Itmp2 = [1 1 2 2 3 3];
        tmp = randperm(6);
        Itmp2 = Itmp2(tmp);

        %// Calculate difference between the next and current neighbor to
        %// check for consecutive (i.e. zeros) and non-consecutive 
        %// presentations (i.e. non-zeros).            
        d = diff(Itmp2);           
        %// Check to see if cond ii is met by finding at least 2
        %// non-consecutive presentations AND no more than 3. If found
        %// set the while escape flag to 1.
        if (length(find(d~=0)) >= 2 && length(find(d~=0)) <= 3) % war vorher 4
            ok = 1;
        end

        %// But wait! We didn't fullfill condition i, so we can't exit
        %// the while loop just yet! Check it with this if statement.
        %// If two or more zeros are present in d, convolution gives for
        %// second+ zero a 2 and max(vector) = 2 which == 2, thus enters
        %// if statement, and while loop continues. Hmm, but when is it
        %// not fullfilled? When the randperm provides three consecutive
        %// pairs, and this should only happen 6 times, since we have 3
        %// pairs that can be permuted. Thus 3! = 6 out of 6! = 720.
        if ok == 1
            if max(conv(double(d==0), double([1 1]))) == 2
                ok = 0;
                sprintf('bam')
            end
        end
```

Comment: in other words, the output is invalid iff it is equal to one of the following matrices?  [1 1 2 2 3 3], [1 1 3 3 2 2], [2 2 1 1 3 3], [2 2 3 3 1 1], [3 3 1 1 2 2], [3 3 2 2 1 1]

Comment: FYI, in matlab a line containing only `%{` starts a comment block, which ends on a line containing only `%}`. Your walls of text are probably easier to read then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could easily just use indexing combined with `isequal` to check this.

```
ok = ~isequal(Itmp2(1:2:end), Itmp2(2:2:end))
```

This simply checks that each element is not equal to the element that follows it in a pair-wise sense.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you want to prevent a case in which 3 different coordinates have identical values from their right.
The following condition will do the trick:

```
ok = sum(conv(Itmp2,[1 -1],'same')==0)~=3
```

Comment: Thanks. Can I avoid using a convolution?

Comment: @Suever avoids convolotion in his answer and it should also work